# Convert a column of instantaneous values to a accumulated values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to convert a column of instantaneous values to a column with accumulated values in Python/Pandas?

Ex.:
I have a pandas data frame with a column:

```
0.1
0.2
0.1
0.4
0.1
```

And I want to create a new column with the accumulated values:

```
0.1
0.3
0.4
0.8
0.9
```

I already tried to loop through it like this:

```
for i in range(1, data_frame.index.size):
    data_frame.new.iloc[i] = data_frame.new.iloc[i-1] + data_frame.old.iloc[i]
```

It works, but take an unacceptable amount of time.

Comment: use df['col'].cumsum()

Comment: Or `np.cumsum(df.col.values)` numpy

Comment: Thank you. I searched the documentation but didn't see cumsum().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `cumsum`:

```
In [157]: df
Out[157]: 
     0
0  0.1
1  0.2
2  0.1
3  0.4
4  0.1

In [158]: df[0].cumsum()
Out[158]: 
0    0.1
1    0.3
2    0.4
3    0.8
4    0.9
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```